# IIS timeout detection

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

I'm investigating an issue where a user is uploading a large document to the web server. This is resulting in a time out at their end. However I'm wondering if it is possible to detect this from the server in order to determine if other users are affected.

There is a connection made while the document is being uploaded. So I'm wondering if IIS 6 is able to detect and record or log anywhere when a client request has timed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by times out. If a client request times out because it cannot connect to the server, or doesn't get a response, this is a client thing, IIS know nothing about it.

If the reason for the time out is an error on the server side, say with a script, then IIS will log this error, but not a timeout.

Answer (score 3):

IIS logs connection timeouts to the HTTPERR log. It should be in C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

Here is a KB article describing what is available in HTTPERR:
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=820729

(as Sam said though - if the problem is client side, it won't show up in an IIS log)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a transaction monitoring service to log the issue from the user side. Use either the iMacros Firefox addon and run the test on your machine, or get a free account at AlertFox and run the test there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the default IIS timeout is only 120 seconds, so it is likely you will need to increase this to accomodate larger files. See [Setting Connection Timeouts to Save Resources (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/31a2f39c-4d59-4cba-905c-60e7af657e49.mspx?mfr=true) for more information and how to set the connection timeouts for IIS 6.0.